# Can "limit" be used regarding a minimum?

Tags: word-usage

For example, suppose there is a sale on candy bars and I buy three, and then the cashier says

> Sorry sir, but the sale price is limited to a minimum purchase of 5 candy bars

Is that a correct usage of the word "limit"?

Or can it only be used with a maximum, such as in

> Speed limit?

Comment: Yes; *lower limit* is idiomatic and common.

Comment: It's the offer that's limited, not the price.

Comment: What Dan Bron and @michael.hor257k are saying is that the answer to your title question is 'yes', but 'Sorry sir, but the sale price is limited to a minimum purchase of 5 candy bars' should be eg 'Sorry sir, but the sale price only applies to a minimum purchase of 5 candy bars'. A reasonable example is 'There is a minimum speed limit of 10 mph in the Mersey Tunnel.'

Comment: The word *limited* can be used with any kind of restriction, not just minimum or maximum; e.g. "*Sorry sir, but the offer is limited to residents of Freedonia.*"

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the phrase “lower limit” does exist. The OED does redirect to “limit”, but its definition of [“limit”](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/limit) does not say that it must be an upper limit. [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lower+limit) defines “lower limit” as:

> **Noun 1. lower limit** - the smallest possible quantity

It also lists “minimum” as a synonym.

Amusement parks often call the minimum and maximum height requirements “limits”. For example, SaferParks titles a page [“Minimum Height Restrictions”](http://www.saferparks.org/safety-tips/minimum-height-restrictions), and says:

> **Why must my child be this tall to ride?**
>
> The amusement ride industry uses **minimum height limits** as a way of restricting the size of riders allowed on board. In some cases, the restriction is tied to the physical size of the rider ...

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/limit

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lower+limit

http://www.saferparks.org/safety-tips/minimum-height-restrictions

Comment: So what I gather is that if I say minimum limit, or lower limit, it should suffice. Though just minimum should be enough, really.

Comment: @DAE Yes, you can use minimum.

Answer (score 3):

It's not terrible-- I don't think it would be misunderstood, but it doesn't sound quite natural or even correct to me. "I'm sorry, but the sale price only applies to purchases of five or more Big Turks". Or "Sorry M'am but the offer is limited to bulk purchases of more than four Mars Bars".

The problem is that the "sale price" is not in itself limited. Sales at the offer price are what is limited.